# Is it possible to emulate non-enumerable properties?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-5, emulation

ES5 has a enumerable flag. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BjrTV/2/)

### Example

```
var getOwnPropertyDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor
 , pd = getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, "toString");

assert(pd.enumerable === false, "enumerability has the wrong value");
```

### Partial implementation

[Partial implementation](https://gist.github.com/1672142) is do-able by having `Object.keys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` filter out new non-enumerable properties using the shimmed `Object.defineProperty`.

### Introduction

This allows for properties to be non enumerable. This clearly means that [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGRDF/2/)

```
for (var key in {}) {
    assert(key !== "toString", "I should never print");
}
```

This allows us to add properties to say `Object.prototype` ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGRDF/1/))

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "toUpperCaseString", {
    value: function toUpperCaseString() {
        return this.toString().toUpperCase();
    },
    enumerable: false
});

for (var key in {}) {
    assert(key !== "toUpperCaseString", "I should never print");
}

console.log(({}).toUpperCaseString()); // "[OBJECT OBJECT]"
```

### Question

How can we emulate this in non-ES5 compliant browsers?

[Browser compat table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)

In this case we care about potentially solving this for

- IE < 9 (IE8 only works on DOM objects)
- Firefox 3.6
- Safari 4
- Opera 11.5 (Opera 11.6 solves this).

The [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) does not have a solution for this.

The ES5 shim has a [solution for *most* ES5 features that will break your code](https://gist.github.com/1664895) if it doesn't work.

Is there any black magic that can be done with propiotory IE only APIs? Maybe with VBScript?

Comment: A shim probably won't ever be able to achieve this, because the behavior of `for... in` is hardwired into the language spec and the interpreter proper. You're asking for something that is just not there in non-ES5-compliant browsers. +1 though, your questions are always interesting.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi after seeing the VB black magic linked above, I'm not so sure of anything anymore.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi My knowledge says "no way is this possible" but browsers have so many weird propietory APIs that it may be possible

Comment: Have you tried traceur? http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/

Comment: @Tom how does traceur help? I can't possibly see how.

Comment: the wiki is down atm but you mentioned ES5; try compiling some ES5 code that does what you need and look at the output.

Comment: @Tom can I try traceur online anywhere?

Comment: @Raynos, you should probably change the `if` in the loop to `console.assert(key !== 'toUpperCaseString', '"toUpperCaseString" should not be enumerable');`

Comment: @zzzzBov `console.assert` is an undocumented feature. I might change it to `assert` though

Comment: This isn't meant to sound sarcastic or anything, but why would I need to do this?

Comment: @j08691 to use ES5 without worrying about it breaking in legacy browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via code-rewriting.  Rewrite every use of `for (p in o) body` to

```
for (p in o) {
  if (!(/^__notenum_/.test(p) || o['__notenum_' + p])) {
    body
  } 
}
```

and then you can mark properties not enumerable by defining a `__notenum_...` property.  To be compatible you would have to tweak the above to make sure that `__notenum_propname` is defined at the same prototype level as `propname`, and if you use them, overwrite `eval` and `new Function` to rewrite.

That's basically what [ES5/3](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/DifferencesBetweenES5Over3AndES5) does.

Comment: Yeah, a code compiler is a solution. An ugly one for ES5 compliance though. As an aside how is ES6/3 coming along?

Comment: @Raynos, if you think emulating property attributes on ES3 is hard, imagine emulating ephemeron tables :)

Comment: I still use the [weakmap shim](https://gist.github.com/1638059) ;) slightly easier.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Don't forget to test against `p` beginning with `__notenum_` - those `__notenum_propname` properties will be enumerable, too!

Answer (score -1):

[**Partial.js**](https://gist.github.com/Raynos/1672142) by [***Jake Verbaten***](https://gist.github.com/Raynos) is the answer to it.

The partial.js is as follows

```
/* partial non-enumerable property implementation

  Adds a flag to a weakmap saying on obj foo property bar is not enumerable.

  Then checks that flag in Object.keys emulation.
*/

// pd.Name :- https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.Name
var enumerables = pd.Name();

Object.defineProperty = function (obj, name, prop) {
    if (prop.enumerable === false) {
         enumerables(obj)[name] = true;
    }
    ...
};

Object.keys = function (obj) {
    var enumerabilityHash = enumerables(obj), keys = [];
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k) && !enumerabilityHash[k]) {
             keys.push(k);
        }
    }
    return keys;
};

Object.getOwnPropertyNames = function (obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var k in obj) { 
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
             keys.push(k);
        }
    }
};
```

I hope this helps the guys searching for this fix.

Comment: this question was about ES3. I already linked my implementation in the question, but it only works in ES5.

Answer (score -2):

If you do care a lot about IE8/IE7 then you can do

```
for (p in o) {
   if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) { body } 
}
```

There is no real "hack" alternative but this could be a work-around for simple cases

The accepted answer doesn't really work for literals i.e. strings `""`, numbers `3`, or booleans `true`