# What is the enumerable argument for in Object.create?

Tags: javascript, object, enumeration, ecmascript-5, enumerable

In what usages of [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) do you want to set `enumerable` to `true`?

Comment: [Emulate non-enumerable properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918030/is-it-possible-to-emulate-non-enumerable-properties)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A property of an object should be enumerable if you want to be able to have access to it when you iterate through all the objects properties. Example:

```
var obj = {prop1: 'val1', prop2:'val2'};
for (var prop in obj){
  console.log(prop, obj[prop]);
}
```

In this type of instantiation, enumerable is always true, this will give you an output of:

```
prop1 val1
prop2 val2
```

If you would have used Object.create() like so:

```
obj = Object.create({}, { prop1: { value: 'val1', enumerable: true}, prop2: { value: 'val2', enumerable: false} });
```

your for loop would only access the prop1, not the prop2. Using Object.create() the properties are set with enumerable = false by default.

Comment: Note that `enumerable` defaults to false in `Object.create`

Comment: thanks, i was referring to the other instantiation. i forgot to mention that. I will edit my answer