# why can not see the added property through Object.create() in console?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var person = {
  kind: 'person'
}

var zack = Object.create(person, {age: {value:  13} });
console.log(zack); 
</script>
```

Question:

in firebug->console, it shows: Object { kind="person"}, why I can not see the added property: age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var zack = Object.create(person, {age: {value:  13, enumerable:true} });
console.log(zack);
```

Answer (score 1):

> in firebug->console, it shows: Object { kind="person"}, why I can not see the added property: age?

`Object.create()` by default doesn't set the enumerable property to true! Since it is false, the property will not be shown up. See [property descriptors at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)(in this case is an accessor descriptor), this is a good reference to start!

> enumerable
>
> true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. **Defaults to false.**

Answer (score 0):

use enumerable: true inside. It should work.

Also check this thread about enumerable property.
[What is the enumerable argument for in Object.create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039860/what-is-the-enumerable-argument-for-in-object-create)