# Adding function to Object prototype causes function to show up in all 'for X in OBJ' loops

Tags: javascript

So, here's some sample javascript code:

```
Object.prototype.simpleFunction = function () {
    return true;
}
var tempObject = {};
for (var temp in tempObject) {
    console.log(temp);
}
```

Note that if you execute this, you'll get 'simpleFunction' output from the `console.log` commands in Google Chrome. (I'm using 19.0.1084.46m .)

However, the wide variety of related Object functions are *not* passed to the `console.log`.

How can I add functions onto the `Object` prototype without them showing up in my '`for property in` object' loops?

**Edit**: I should have mentioned that the last thing I wanted was to throw another 'if' statement in there, as it'd mean I'd need to add it to ALL `for` loops.  :(

Comment: See [How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Which is why you should always check `hasOwnProperty`:

```
for (var temp in tempObject) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(tempObject, temp)) {
        console.log(temp);
    }
}
```

Crockford advocates using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` instead of `tempObject.hasOwnProperty`, just in case you override `hasOwnProperty` in your object.

---

In ES5, you can set it to not be `enumerable`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'simpleFunction', {
    value: function() {
        return true;
    },
    enumerable: false, // this is actually the default
});
```

Alternatively (in ES5), you can use `Object.keys()` to only get the object's own keys:

```
Object.keys(tempObject).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: I was looking up enumerable:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918030/is-it-possible-to-emulate-non-enumerable-properties  :  It looks like that enumerable is the answer, even if it's not widely supported yet.   I'll be checking compatibility while I work in development.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
for (var temp in tempObject) {
    if (tempObject.hasOwnProperty(temp )) {
         console.log(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the inherited properties by doing this:

```
if (tempObject.hasOwnProperty(temp)) {
    // property didn't come from the prototype chain
}
```

The bottom line is, you can't add functions to the prototype without having them being iterated using `in`.

You could define an external interface in which you always pass the object, e.g.

```
function simpleFunction(obj) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this in javascript. You need to filter the results yourself. One potential method is to define your own prototype properties in another object:

```
var myObjectExt = {
    sampleFunciton: function(){}
}
var p;
for(p in myObjectExt){
    Object.prototype[p] = myObjectExt[p];
}

var obj = {};
for(p in obj){
    if(myObjectExt[p])continue;
    //do what you need
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty good wrapper function in case I need to add more than one function to Object.prototype and can't use `enumerable`.  :)  Thanks!