# How was Object.create() with second parameter accomplished prior to ECMAScript 5?

Tags: javascript

When dealing with `Object.create()` I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020265/object-create-not-supported-in-ie8) and in summary it mentions:

- polyfill that was used to retrofit IE8 with `Object.create`
  functionality, however this polyfill doesn't support a second parameter
- shim which requires inclusion of [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/)

with various trains of thought on how to best accomplish this.

Here's my relevant code I am using:

```
//json_string variable is passed via php

var arrayOfOptions = jQuery.parseJSON(json_string);

var template = {
     // my instance that I want to initialize based on the properties provided
};

var instance = Object.create(template, {'options':{value:arrayOfOptions, enumerable: true}});
```

My question is how did programmers accomplish this task prior to ES5, and more specifically what would be a better/alternative implementations of initializing an object based on on a set of passed properties without utilizing the second parameter?

Comment: you could not,expect for native dom objects on ie8.

Comment: here's a question that covers the enumerable property setting prior to ES5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918030/is-it-possible-to-emulate-non-enumerable-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how did programmers accomplish this task prior to ES5

Not at all. There had been [property attributes](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.1) in ES3, but there was no way to set them. There was no `Object.create` as well. There just had been [`.propertyIsEnumerable()`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.2.4.7) to get the `DontEnum` flag.

> what would be a better/alternative implementations of initializing an object based on on a set of passed properties without utilizing the second parameter?

Use an `extend` function. Example with jQuery:

```
var instance = $.extend(Object.create(template), {options:arrayOfOptions});
```

Example with self-made helper function:

```
function createAndExtend(proto, props) {
    var o = Object.create(proto);
    for (var p in props)
        o[p] = props[p];
    return o;
}
var instance = createAndExtend(template, {options:arrayOfOptions});
```

You hardly ever need property descriptors anyway.